# how to get gcc or g++ command when using "colcon build" in ros2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in ros2 ardent version, I can get compile command by "set(CMAKE_VEBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)" in CmakeLists.txt, but I can't find these message in ros2 bouncy, anyone can help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301002/how-to-get-gcc-or-g++-command-when-using-%22colcon-build%22-in-ros2?/) by [lxbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/36253/lxbeyond/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-08-20**:
You mean when you start the build? You can do something like: `--cmake-args -CMAKE_VEBOSE_MAKEFILE=TRUE` when launching colcon command line.

**Comment by [mschickler](https://answers.ros.org/users/48984/mschickler/) on 2020-06-19**:
I think this is actually supposed to be "--cmake-args -DCMAKE_VEBOSE_MAKEFILE=TRUE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the CMake code hasn't changed I would expect `colcon` to behave the same as `ament_tools` (since it is basically invoking CMake and Make for you).

By default `colcon` doesn't show the output from `stdout`. Have you tried enabling the output as mentioned in the [docs](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/how-to.html#show-all-output-on-the-console-after-a-package-has-finished)?

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0